# Failed to load resource error after using a bundler

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, axios

I was finally able to import and use axios by installing a bundler (parcel bundler). I configured it, but now when I run the server I receive an "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" error for `localhost/:1`, which takes me to the first line of `index.html` in the inspect window after I click it.

Some pictures to clarify:
[image]

[image]

This is strange because the website loads and is visible (which wouldn't have been possible if it couldn't load `index.html` as that is what is being shown) so maybe I am not getting right what this error even means.

Comment: mmm what do you mean by when you run the server? A separate server or Parcel server?

Comment: A parcel server (not sure what is the difference between a local one and the parcel one).

Comment: If you are using Parcel, you are probably doing something like this: `parcel index.html`. If that is the case it is weird that you are getting an error since Parcel is so simple that is does everything for you.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have in the `package.json` scripts.

Comment: Can you create a CodeSanbox? It is a little difficult to figure out the problem without seeing actual code.

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hoover-trcjr The javascript code is a bit problematic there but it is negligible for this case. Also, I commented the import statement for axios.

Comment: What you are seeing is probably what is usually called "History API fallback". If dev server doesn't find a file/bundle you are requesting, it will serve you default `index.html`.

Comment: Any idea what it happens? I installed axios as shown in many guides and everything is up to date...